# PyTorch Lightning multi node training error on GCP

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, ray, pytorch-lightning, distributed-training

We are currently working on a project that involves training on Pytorch Lightning. The code utilizes GPUs through DistributedDataParallel (DDP). Currently, it is working fine while running on a single machine of Vertex AI Training job and/or on Notebooks.

But when we try the same with multi-node training (involving master & worker pools), The training doesn't initiate as the code just runs on the master node, without utilizing the worker machines. Here is the code for training -

```
trainer = pl.Trainer(
        max_epochs=num_epochs,
        weights_summary='full',
        callbacks=callbacks,
        accelerator='ddp',
        gpus=-1,
        num_sanity_val_steps=0,
        limit_train_batches=limit_train_batches,
        limit_val_batches=limit_val_batches,
    )
```

Q1 - Is there any way to call the worker nodes in the training job?

---

Also we did stumble across a module called Ray Lightning, that can assist with the same objective. But implementation of the same is causing some bugs... It's not getting initialized despite specifying the following commands in the code -

```
os.system('ray up cluster.yml')
ray.init(address="auto")
trainer = pl.Trainer(
        max_epochs=num_epochs,
        weights_summary='full',
        callbacks=callbacks,
        accelerator='ddp',
        plugins=[RayPlugin(num_workers=num_workers, use_gpu=use_gpu)],
        num_sanity_val_steps=0,
        limit_train_batches=limit_train_batches,
        limit_val_batches=limit_val_batches,
    )
```

Q2 - Any possible fixes for the current problem?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, my rank 0 pod was training and logging but the non-rank 0 pods were just hanging. I ssh'd into the non rank 0 pods and ran "nvidia-smi" and all of them were utilising their GPUs. This could mean that they just *appear* to not be training just because they are not logging. I can't be sure of this though. Might be worth checking the same thing for your system?

p.s my system is pytorch-lightning deployed on in-house kubernetes cluster

Comment: turns out elasticity isn't currently support for pytorch-lightning: https://github.com/PyTorchLightning/pytorch-lightning/issues/10180 https://github.com/PyTorchLightning/pytorch-lightning/issues/9063